# Obtener un dato al azar de la base de datos si cumple una condición

Tags: php, sql

Tengo mil datos guardados en la base de datos y me los imprime todos, lo que me interesa es obtener un dato al azar de esa base de datos siempre y cuando cumpla una condición.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM $base WHERE condicion a cumplir");

while($view = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {}
```

Comment: con un where en la consulta?

Comment: @gbianchi Según tengo entendido es para validar si los datos coinciden...

Comment: Que cosa? un where? un where, tambien, filtra los datos segun algun criterio.. o eso, o haces un limit en tu consulta para que solo traiga una cantidad n de filas...

Comment: @gbianchi Ya entiendo, lo que sucede es que hasta ahora estoy aprendiendo algo de php y no sé cómo hacer esa consulta especificando cantidad de resultados.

Comment: php no tiene nada que ver aca... es sql el tema...

Comment: Entiendo, lo que me interesa es seleccionar un dato al azar de esa tabla, porque ya probé con LIMIT - cantidad - pero muestra en el orden de la tabla y pues obviamente el primer dato siempre va a ser el usado.

Comment: ¿Y cual sería esa condición a cumplir?, por otro lado por favor provee un [mcve]

Comment: @BetaM Ya agregué la otra línea, solo estoy utilizando esas dos funciones.

Comment: pero muestra en el orden de la tabla y pues obviamente el primer dato siempre va a ser el usado <- totalmetne falso.. un query nunca asegura como van a venir los datos, salvo que pongas una clausula order by.. que venga alugno en particular es porque a la base de datos le cuesta menos buscarlo... si queres un dato random, tenes que generar una funcion para buscarlo...

Comment: No es lo más eficiente, pero puedes [ordenar la consulta al azar](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/select-random-records-database-table.aspx/). Aparte, agrega [LIMIT 1](https://www.anerbarrena.com/mysql-limit-5553/) para leer solo una fila.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres apoyarte en `PHP` puedes usar la función `rand()` la cual recibe dos parámetros, **el valor mínimo** y **el valor máximo**. Esta función te sirve para generar un número entero aleatorio. Con este número puedes jugar para generar un resultado igualmente aleatorio.

Por ejemplo, si tienes mil registros con un identificador único, puedes usar la función de la siguiente manera:

```
$aleatorio = rand(1, 1000);
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM $base WHERE idUnico = $aleatorio");
```

[En este enlace encuentras información adicional:](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.rand.php)